# ¿Cómo crear variables independientes dentro de funciones que están siendo disparadas por eventos delegados?

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo crear variables independientes para cada elemento en funciones que están siendo disparadas desde eventos delegados?
De forma más clara, tengo varios slides de imágenes en una misma página, y uso un contador para desplazarlos, pero al tener un solo contador, al hacer click sobre un slide afecta y termina bugeando a los demás, haciendo que se salten posiciones, o se queden trabados.

Lo que necesito básicamente es que cada slide tenga su propio contador local para que se puedan desplazar independientemente sin afectas a los demás, aquí mi código

```
let container = document.getElementsByClassName("slides-container");
let click = 0;

for (const slide of container) {
  slide.addEventListener("click", delegar);
}

function delegar(e) {
  const clase = e.target.classList[0];
  const elemento = e.target.parentNode.previousElementSibling;
  const puntos = e.target.parentNode;
  
  if (clase === "btnNext") {
    moveForward();
  } else if (clase === "btnPrev") {
    moveBackward();
  }

  function moveForward() {
    switch (click) {
      case 0:
        elemento.style.transform = "translateX(-33%)";
        click++;
        break;
      case 1:
        elemento.style.transform = "translateX(-66%)";
        click++;
        break;
    }
  }

  function moveBackward() {
    switch (click) {
      case 2:
        elemento.style.transform = "translateX(-33%)";
        click--;
        break;
      case 1:
        elemento.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
        click--;
        break;
    }
  }
  console.log(click);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar crear contadores por cada *slider*, puedes agregar una propiedad personalizada, aunque lo ideal sería usar [atributos de datos (dataset)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos), pero funciona.

- Dentro del ciclo, crea la propiedad para contar los clics
- Asegúrate de obtener el contenedor adecuado usando [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), así evitas cualquier posible error
- Debes enviar el elemento a las funciones donde necesites acceder o modificar la propiedad `.click`

```
let container = document.getElementsByClassName("slides-container");

for (const slide of container) {
  // Agregar propiedad en el elemento
  slide.click = 0;
  slide.addEventListener("click", delegar);
}

function delegar(e) {
  const clase = e.target.classList[0];
  // Asegurar que el elemento es el adecuado usando closest() y clase
  const elemento = e.target.closest('.slides-container');
  const puntos = e.target.parentNode;
  
  if (clase === "btnNext") {
    // Se debe enviar parámetro
    moveForward(elemento);
  } else if (clase === "btnPrev") {
    moveBackward(elemento);
  }

  // Recibir por parámetro
  function moveForward(slide) {
    // Analizar la propiedad creada e incrementar si se cumple condición
    switch (slide.click) {
      case 0:
        slide.style.transform = "translateX(-33%)";
        slide.click++;
        break;
      case 1:
        slide.style.transform = "translateX(-66%)";
        slide.click++;
        break;
    }
  }

  function moveBackward(slide) {
    switch (slide.click) {
      case 2:
        slide.style.transform = "translateX(-33%)";
        slide.click--;
        break;
      case 1:
        slide.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
        slide.click--;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto modificando algunas cosillas para adaptarlo a la estructura del sitio, muchísimas gracias!